# I have several iPhones / iPads, and when I say "Hey Siri what's the weather tomorrow", only my main phone will respond, how is it designed?

Tags: iphone, ios, siri

That's is, if I have several iPhones and iPads on the desk for lying there for an hour, and I just said, "Hey Siri..." without touching any of the devices, only the phone that I use most often will respond. Does Siri know which one is my main phone and only use it to respond?

Comment: It will help if you can edit  the question to include the make of iPhones and iPads that you use along with the version of iOS running on them. Not all of the current breed of iOS devices support "Hey Siri". See [this](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204389#hey) support article.

Answer (score 5):

When you say "Hey Siri", the devices that could possibly react to it will communicate with each other using Bluetooth to determine which device will respond: The device that heard you best, or the device that was most recently raised or used will respond to the "Hey Siri" request.

Apple has detailed the method here:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208472

Comment: this is a design that would make Steve Jobs feel pleased

Answer (score -3):

"Hey Siri" only really works on select newer iPhones. I had an iPhone 6 for a while and had the option for "Hey Siri" but it never worked. Upon getting an iPhone 7 plus... The "Hey Siri" feature works great!
Your main phone must be newer than the others if "Hey Siri" only works on that one.
That or "Hey Siri" is disabled on the other phones and/or iPads.